# Computer Science A level, PSEUDOCODE question

Tags: computer-science, pseudocode

I was given this problem in class and had to come up with a solution to the problem in pseudocode. Here is the problem(quite long sorry):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXGfb.png

And here is the mark scheme(solution) we were given:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkXSm.png

My solution is here:

```
counter = 0 
red_score = 0
blue_score = 0
red_highscore = 0
blue_highscore = 0

while scores to compare:
    if player_score[counter][0] == 0 THEN
        blue_Score = blue_score + player_score[counter][1]
        if player_score[counter][1] > blue_highscore THEN
            blue_highscore = player_score[counter][1] : player_name[counter]
ELSE
        red_Score = red_score + player_score[counter][1]
        if player_score[counter][1] > red_highscore THEN
            red_highscore = player_score[counter][1] : player_name[counter]
END IF
counter = counter + 1
END WHILE
    
OUTPUT 'Winning team'

if red_score > blue_score THEN 
    OUTPUT 'Blue team'
ELSE
    OUTPUT 'Red team'

OUTPUT 'Red Team Total Score', red_score
OUTPUT 'Blue Team Total Score', blue_score
OUTPUT 'Highest score in Red Team', red_player(player_name)
OUTPUT 'Highest score in Blue Team', blue_player(player_name)
```

Now I know pseudocode is informal and both answers are likely to be different but I don't understand how the counter was being used in the first example, as in a 2D array doesn't it have two values so just doing 'blue_score=blue_score+score(counter)' would not work. Also if the counter was used at the start 'IF player(counter)=0 THEN' once the counter then increases to more than 2 then what team will it add the score to since the teams are only 0 and 1.

Obviously, I could be totally wrong here but just wanted to understand where I went wrong if I am.

Many thanks

Comment: Oh ok. So have I got it wrong lol? Because I thought there was 1 1D array and 1 2D array

Comment: I moved my comment to an answer to get more space :-)

Answer (score 0):

It does seem a little confused. In the given solution, players are identified by number, and there are three 1-D arrays: player, player_name, and score. The first of these is used to determine the team of the player.

You're apparently following the written instructions and considering player() and score() as a combined 2-D array.

```
if player_score[counter][0] == 0 THEN
    blue_Score = blue_score + player_score[counter][1]
```

So, there's a row per player; the first column has team membership, and the second has score.  That seems ok to me (though I think the separate arrays make more logical sense, but that's not what was asked of you).

'counter' selects the player, and thus goes 0, 1, 2, ...

The second index, 0 or 1, selects the team-membership or score column.

Comment: Ohhhh. So the mark scheme has done it based on 3, 1D arrays when it was asked to do 1D array and 1, 2D array?

Comment: That's what it looks like from here.  Insufficient proof-reading by someone :-)

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot more sense. Did you do CS for levels?

Comment: CS A-level wasn't invented when I was at school.  Or at least not at my school.

Comment: Do you have any tips for learning pseudocode and python as I understand the theory well, its just this that sometimes confuses me

Comment: Is 'pseudocode' a specific thing for your studies?   In general, any old notation that adequately conveys the algorithm is acceptable pseudocode, but that might not be true in your specific use.   But really, I think you're just asking how to convert ideas to code, pseudo or otherwise, and my only answer to that is 'keep doing it'.  If there are programs you want to write (as opposed to programs someone's telling you to write), then that is highly motivating.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I actually think the pseudo-code is pretty okay in the respects you highlighted: what's throwing you off is just that the details of indexing into the arrays are being abstracted away.

So, consider that the algorithm expects `i` data points (including a score, a player name, and a team id) as input, and these data points are being looped over with the `counter` variable. For some particular value of counter, `counter = i`, interpret their `player(counter)` as just a function or operation to get the i'th player's team, or as just representing that team value directly (a better name for this would probably be `team(counter)`). Similarly, take `score(counter)` as representing the i'th score. The particular data structures being used to store player/team names and scores and how exactly you index into those data structures are the kind of details that are perfectly reasonable and pretty much expected to abstract away in pseudocode.

That is, you probably won't find a lot of pseudocode with expressions like `player_scores[counter][0]` and `player_scores[counter][1]` which lock an algorithm into a particular, 2d-array based implementation where team information is somewhat arbitrarily put into the first slot of the rows of some array and score into those rows' second slot, etc. It's much more common to just use the kind of functional shorthand in the given solution. It's hard to know to avoid that sort of thing when you're given all the array-based implementation details in the problem statement, but it's pretty standard style.

I would actually say the fact that an implementation might hard-code 0 and 1 to represent the blue and red teams is another particularity that shouldn't be in the pseudocode. That is, it'd be an improvement to replace their `IF player(counter)=0` check for whether the i'th data entry pertains to the blue team with `IF team(counter)=blue`. One other confusing thing about their pseudocode is that they're mixing equality (`=`) and assignment operators (typically `:=` in pseudocode). For example, it would be more common to see `blue_player:=counter` than `blue_player=counter` when you're setting the variable `blue_player` to have the current value of `counter`, and you would reserve `=` (without the colon) for comparisons. But overall, the abstraction they do provide is a good thing.

Comment: How do I know what parts I should focus on abstracting in the future?

Comment: And thank you very much

Comment: You're generally just trying to describe an algorithm as concisely and clearly as possible. You don't want implementation details and language-specific syntax to get in the way of that, though knowing what those are comes with a bit of experience. Python-style is pretty brief and pseudo-code like, as it omits most variable and type declarations, which you should too unless the type is particularly relevant. If it's shorter or clearer to replace any expression or a function block with a phrase in English then go for it.

Comment: Reading algorithm pseudocode online or in books definitely helps, as there are many ways to do it, and what's best is subjective. The goal is just to describe the essential steps of an algorithm in a way any programmer could quickly and easily understand and then implement in whatever language they choose, and if you're doing that well, then you're writing effective pseudocode.